# cannot start roscore

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this is error i got when i start the roscore.

[rosout-1] process has died

why is this happening?.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186799/cannot-start-roscore/) by [robospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/18911/robospace/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-07-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is that happening for Indigo for you, too? If yes it might be related to https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/465

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same error using the latest ROS Indigo build with an uptodate Ubuntu 14.04.

> roscore

yielded:

```
started roslaunch server http://benni-notebook:58480/
ros_comm version 1.11.6


SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.6

NODES

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [22300]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://benni-notebook:11311/

setting /run_id to 6e5bfafc-0db4-11e4-ba26-1867b02b12d1
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [22313]
started core service [/rosout]
[rosout-1] process has died [pid 22313, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/rosout/rosout __name:=rosout __log:=/home/benni/.ros/log/6e5bfafc-0db4-11e4-ba26-1867b02b12d1/rosout-1.log].
log file: /home/benni/.ros/log/6e5bfafc-0db4-11e4-ba26-1867b02b12d1/rosout-1*.log
[rosout-1] restarting process
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [22320]
[rosout-1] process has died [pid 22320, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/rosout/rosout __name:=rosout __log:=/home/benni/.ros/log/6e5bfafc-0db4-11e4-ba26-1867b02b12d1/rosout-1.log].
log file: /home/benni/.ros/log/6e5bfafc-0db4-11e4-ba26-1867b02b12d1/rosout-1*.log
[rosout-1] restarting process
```

Strangely enough the problem only occured while I was connected to a VPN (using NetworkManager). So I could bypass the issue by simply starting the roscore while not beeing connected to a VPN.
I dont know the reason for this behaviour but I did a

> gdb rosout

```
    Starting program: /opt/ros/indigo/lib/rosout/rosout 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7b41cc7 in ros::Transport::Transport() () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7b41cc7 in ros::Transport::Transport() () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so
#1  0x00007ffff7b4d1e0 in ros::TransportTCP::TransportTCP(ros::PollSet*, int) ()
   from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so
#2  0x00007ffff7b3c828 in ros::ConnectionManager::start() ()
   from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so
#3  0x00007ffff7b5f049 in ros::start() () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so
#4  0x00007ffff7b39d51 in ros::NodeHandle::construct(std::string const&, bool) ()
   from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so
#5  0x00007ffff7b3a03f in ros::NodeHandle::NodeHandle(std::string const&, std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > > const&) () from /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so
#6  0x0000000000407ca1 in main ()
```

---

Originally posted by [grim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1357/grim/) with karma: 101 on 2014-07-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2014-07-17**:
Same for me: I get the same errors when starting up a roscore while I'm connected to a VPN. Works fine without VPN.

**Comment by [robospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/18911/robospace/) on 2014-07-18**:
I'am not connected to VPN but still i get this message

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I' m running ROS Indigo on a rasberry raspian jessie installation. After evoking roscore, I' getting:

process[rosout-1]: started with pid [955]
[rosout-1] process has died [pid 955, exit code -4, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/rosout/rosout __name:=rosout __log:=/home/pi/.ros/log/ec132a8c-8c3b-11e4-834d-b827eb2156d2/rosout-1.log].
log file: /home/pi/.ros/log/ec132a8c-8c3b-11e4-834d-b827eb2156d2/rosout-1*.log
[rosout-1] restarting process

Any idea, to what this problem is related?

Thanks

---

Originally posted by [MartinHummel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4385/martinhummel/) with karma: 156 on 2014-12-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2